# Is there an integral domain in which all elements are reducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is there an integral domain in which all elements are reducible?

I can't think of a counter example. Some sugestion?

Comment: What do you mean "integrity ring"? Do you mean integral domain https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain?

Comment: Vacuously, a field has this property. But I guess this is not what you're after :)

Comment: Yes, Integral Domain, i speak portuguese, sorry.

Comment: Consider the ring $R=\bigcup_n{k[[X^{1/n!}]]}$.

Comment: **Hint** [Consider](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/37501/242) a domain, not a field, that is closed under square-roots. It has no irreducibles since every element factors $\rm\ d\ =\ \sqrt{d}\ \sqrt{d}\:.\ $  For example, the domain of all algebraic integers.  Such domains are known as **antimatter** domains so you can learn more by searching on that term.

Answer (score 0):

The adjectives "reducible" and "irreducible" are typically only taken to apply to nonzero, nonunit elements of an integral domain.

So if you want an integral domain which has lots of nonzero, nonunit elements that are reducible, and no irreducible elements, then the ring of algebraic integers is an example. Every such element is the square of another element.